# Can TLS-enabled rsyslog use a certificate revocation list?

Tags: tls, rsyslog

When using the gtls driver, is it possible to configure rsyslog to use a certificate revocation list? We are running rsyslogd 5.8.10 (standard in CentOS 6.5).